# java: Understanding the LRU implementation

Tags: java

I am trying to understand given below LRU implementation. Could not figure out the following:

1. What is the use of `addFirst()`. This method is being called from both `put` and `get` method.
2. How the doubly linked list helping to track the oldest entry? All the entries are actually in the map where one entry does not know about the other one.

These questions may sound stupid but I would really appreciate the explanation.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class LRUDLL<K, V> {

private final Map<K, Entry<K,V>> map;
private Entry<K, V> oldest;
private final int lruSize;

public LRUDLL (int lruSize) {
    if(lruSize <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size is inappropriate");
    }
    map = new HashMap<K, Entry<K, V>>();
    this.lruSize = lruSize;
}


    private static class Entry<K, V> {
        Entry<K, V> left;
        Entry<K, V> right;
        K key;
        V value;

        Entry(Entry<K, V> left, K key, V value, Entry<K, V> right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.right = right;
        }
    };

    private void addFirst(Entry<K, V> entry) {
        remove(entry);
        if(oldest == null) {
            entry.left = entry.right = entry;
            oldest = entry;
        } else {
            Entry<K, V> tail = entry;

            tail.right = entry;
            entry.left = tail;

            //deal with circulating
            oldest.left = entry;
            entry.right = oldest;
        }
    }

    private void remove (Entry<K, V> entry) {
        assert entry != null;

        if(entry.left != null) entry.left.right = entry.right;
        if(entry.right != null) entry.right.left = entry.left;
        if(entry == oldest) oldest = entry.right;
    }

    public synchronized void put (K key, V value) {
        Entry<K, V> entry = new Entry<K, V>(null, key, value, null);
        map.put(key, entry);
        addFirst(entry);
        if(removeOldestEntry()) {
            remove(oldest);
        }
    }

    public synchronized V get(K key) {
        Entry<K, V> entry = map.get(key);
        if(entry!= null) {
            addFirst(entry);
            return entry.value;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean removeOldestEntry() {
        return map.size() > lruSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: no question is stupid man. didn't u overload addfirst method?

Comment: Nope. I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key point here is that it's not just a doubly-linked list, it's a *circular* doubly-linked list. So `oldest` is the *least*-recently-used element, `oldest.right` is the *second-least*-recently-used element, . . . and `oldest.left` is the *most*-recently-used element. (And `oldest.left.left` is the *second-most*-recently-used element, and so on.)

I'm not sure why it was done this way — it seems like it would be simpler to have an `oldest` pointing at the least-recently-used and a `newest` pointing at the most-recently-used — but it doesn't really matter.

> What is the use of `addFirst()`. This method is being called from both `put` and `get` method.

`addFirst` removes the specified entry from its current location in the list, and adds it to the left of `oldest`, thereby marking it as the most-recently-used element.

> How the doubly linked list helping to track the oldest entry? All the entries are actually in the map where one entry does not know about the other one.

Well, so there's a serious bug in this implementation: it never actually removes any element from `map`, so it's not actually an LRU cache. Worse yet, it never nulls out the `left` and `right` on the entries it supposedly "removes", which means that when those entries are subsequently retrieved from `map`, and re-`addFirst`-ed, the list sequence ends up completely wrong. So the implementation is quite broken.

But how it's *supposed* to work is this: `map` just has all the entries, but it doesn't know anything about which one is least-recently-used. The list keeps all the elements in order by how recently they were used, so at any given time, `oldest` is the least-recently-used.

(The underlying reason for the bug is that `remove` is being used for two separate things: `addFirst` just needs it to remove an element from its position in the list, so it can be moved to a new position, while `put` actually needs to be able to remove the `oldest` from `map`. Probably the current version of `remove` should be inlined into `addFirst`, and a new `removeOldest` should be created that actually removes the oldest element.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in detail. Do you know simpler LRU implementation without using `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav: This implementation is an excellent start, it just has one serious bug and one minor point of unnecessary complexity. To address the serious bug, see my last paragraph. To simplify the complexity, just add a `newest` field alongside your `oldest`. `newest.right` and `oldest.left` will be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the use of addFirst(). This method is being called from both
>   put and get method.

A Least Recently Used data structure needs to update when an entry is accessed. When you `put`, you want to add the entry to the front because it's the most recently used. When you `get` an entry from the LRU, it's again the most recently used, so bring it to the front of the LRU.

> How the doubly linked list helping to track the oldest entry? All the
>   entries are actually in the map where one entry does not know about
>   the other one.

Check out the implementation of `LinkedHashMap`. The doubly linked list mantains access order. Each entry knows which entry was accessed before and after it.